# flutter gridview builder is choppy/laggy but it's just a tile of (very) low-res images

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gridview, flutter-gridview

### Short Question

Is it a bad idea to have gridview builder find (and render) an image file every time it needs to build? Any alternative approach?

### Long Question

I'm developing a flutter/dart media gallery grid.

I'm using the gridview builder since there could be any arbitrary amount of items I need to display, so need to consider perormance.

All I'm doing is simply pulling a list of image meta data (very light records) into memory (`dataMedia`), and when gridview builder needs to render one, it'll take the ID from that `dataMedia` item and (within the components in my media list) will pull that file in.

It's laggy/choppy/jittery/however you want to describe it. I assume it's doing a bit of work in finding the file and then rendering it.

### What I've Tried

I've tried really dropping the quality of my images to the extreme just for testing. I can see the quality of the images is really, really poor so that rules out any issues rendering hi-res.

I've also tried pulling all of the images into memory so that it can pluck what it needs from a local collection rather than go to the disk, but I get `OutOfMemoryException` (it's not feasible to pull *all* images into memory).

I've also tried this on other devices, but the device it's happening on (the mobile phone I'm using for dev) is a decent spec S20 ultra. So I don't believe it's struggling because of a sub-par phone spec.

### Media List

```
                    GridView.builder(
                            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: 4,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                              childAspectRatio: 1,
                            ),
                            itemCount: dataMedia.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, dataMediaIndex) {
                              final dataMediaItem = dataMedia[dataMediaIndex];
                              return InkWell(
                                child: MediaitemWidget(
                                  id: dataMediaItem.id
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          )
```

### Media Item

```
  return Stack(
      children: [
        Image.file(File('/myAppPath/${widget.id}.jpg')),
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than debugging, I built out the APK (which would be in release mode) and it performs perfectly!

I guess having a debugger attached to the process causes lag? That's understandable.